# 'how many of us' vs. 'how many of we'

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Which is correct:
'My friend asked how many of us are going to watch the Superbowl' 
or 
'My friend asked how many of we are going to watch the Superbowl'

Note: 'my friend' is not a part of the group implied by we/us, but the speaker is a part of that group.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

"How many of we" is ungrammatical, just like "the two of we", "there is only one of I" or "look at the three of they".

Actually, not only after "of", but in general, after a preposition, at least in most cases, you use the oblique form of the personal pronoun:

> He talked *about* **me**.
>
> He looked *at* **us**.

And so, in the same way:

> How many *of* **us** are going to watch?

See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_case

Comment: Of course now that this, um, *strange* question is up, I am gonna play devil's advocate and say that "in general, after a preposition, you use the oblique form of the personal pronoun" is oversimplifying things. COCA has 199 occurrences of "of we". "The admiration of we don't know what", "the issue of 'we can't live in Denver'", "which there is a couple of we need to mention", "They are part of We the People", and countless "kind of/sort of we are blah".

Comment: Added `in most cases` to accommodate for the implications of your very astute remark and your 199 occurrences :)

Comment: RegDwigнt is quite correct, of course, but those are edge cases (uncommon examples). The vast majority of everyday examples will use a noun phrase as the object of the preposition, rather than clauses that occur immediately following a preposition (or even adverb). It is accurate to say that "of we" *can* be correct, but it's worth noting (particularly for those new to English grammar) that "of us" is dramatically more likely to be grammatically correct in any given sentence (statistically speaking).

Answer (score 3):

The object of a preposition (of, around, about, to, near, through, etc.) takes the **accusative case** of pronouns (*me, him, her, us, them, whom, etc.*)

**Who** may I say is calling? / **To whom** do you wish to speak?
**He** is talking to my sister. / My sister is talking **to him**.

Answer (score 0):

You can say: 'there are two/three/four etc of us'; or 'we are two/three/four etc'.

The latter is less common than the former but is often used when speaking to a waiter/box-office attendant etc to explain how many seats, tickets etc you need.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer Susan's formulation: After a preposition follows an accusative (in English grammars they call it object case which is the same). And there is no exception. -  The hint at "a friend of mine" is a specialty of English (and the question what case "mine" is would probably lead to a big discussion. But for me "mine" is also an accusative. Of course, the whole group "of+mine" is no accusative.) I would avoid the term oblique case. That is really no useful grammar term for English. Linguists can use "oblique case" and write papers about what it is. In English grammar you have the terms subject case, object case, indirect object and possessive case.
In Latin terms it is - at least for me - much clearer: nominative, accusative, dative, genitive. And if you want you can introduce the term "prepositive" for cases consisting of 
preposition + noun (except of and to). But that is no official term. I use it because it is practical.

Comment: In English, you have unmarked/subject and marked/oblique case (as well as a genitive case in some pronouns). Simple as that. There are no distinct object and indirect object cases, nor any true accusative or dative cases; and labelling it ‘object case’ only confuses things.

Comment: Would you please define "oblique case" for me. I know the term, but not in English grammar, and probably my concept of oblique case is different from yours.

Comment: An oblique case is simply a default case that performs all other roles than the case(s) otherwise listed in the system. For example, the marked/oblique case in English is used for both direct objects (accusative), indirect objects (dative), prepositional objects (a variety of case types), and increasingly for subject complements and non-verbal phrases. The unmarked case (subject case) is used only for its own, limited purpose; the oblique case does everything else.

Comment: I used the link i posted earlier: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_case .

Comment: I'm not certain whether the author of that wikipedia article really understands what he is talking about. But try to explain what wikipedia says to a learner and see if he is happy with your explanation. I have several linguistic dictionaries and you can only guess what really is meant with oblique case. Every author gives another definition. For me a useless term, especially for English grammar.